# Enviar post a otra web y recibir el resultado

Tags: php

En mi servidor tengo un checker que usa un servidor externo para obtener respuesta, pero esa respuesta se muestra en el servidor externo y yo quiero que se muestre en mi servidor.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se muestre esa respuesta en mi servidor?

El form que envia es el siguiente:

```
<form method="POST" action="chk.php" style="margin-top:2%">
    <p><input type="text" style="padding: 15px 10px 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',arial black,sans-serif; border: 1px solid #cecece;  color: black;box-sizing: border-box; width: 60%;  max-width: 450px;" name="imei" autocomplete="off" maxlength="30" placeholder="IMEI or Serial Number">



    <button onclick="ButtonClicked();  " type="submit" ;="" style="background-color: ; padding: 10px 25px;  border: 2px solid #b2b2b2; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; width: 20%; max-width: 100px; color: #000000;"><font size="4,5">Search</font></button></form>
```

Y este es el código que tenia planeado usar para enviar y obtener la respuesta pero no he podido hacer que funcione ya que no me enseña respuesta solo obtengo un error.

```
<?php
$imei = utf8_decode($_POST['imei']);

//Lo primerito, creamos una variable iniciando curl, pasándole la url
$ch = curl_init('https://otraweb.com/chek.php');

//especificamos el POST (tambien podemos hacer peticiones enviando datos por GET
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//le decimos qué paramáetros enviamos (pares nombre/valor, también acepta un array)
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "imei=$imei");

//le decimos que queremos recoger una respuesta (si no esperas respuesta, ponlo a false)
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true)

//recogemos la respuesta
$respuesta = curl_exec ($ch);

//o el error, por si falla
$error = curl_error($ch);

//y finalmente cerramos curl
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Puedes usar curl para enviar los datos de tu form y de paso obtener el resultado.

Comment: @juan valdez Bienvenido. Se que es tu primera vez acá, pero para dar mas importancia a tu publicación trata de poner código o algún avance de lo que llevas , eso te dará un plus para que la ayuda sea mas amena. Edita tu pregunta y re formula de nuevo.Saludos.

Comment: hola @SebastiánLagosYañez ya edite y puse el codigo

Answer (score -1):

El error puede ser que estas en un servidor diferente
Agrega este header para permitir el acceso desde otro origen

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

también podes especificar una URL como origen de la petición en lugar de todas (*)

mas info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Gracias por responder pero si no tengo acceso al servidor diferente entonces no puedo obtener la respuesta?

Comment: exactamente, podes simular ser un navegante accediendo a la pagina del formulario original, guardar las cookies, parsear el form y enviarlo. pero este tipo de técnicas se cae si hay un captcha o javascript que modifica la petición, o cualquier otro tipo de mecanismo tendiente a evitar justamente eso el intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado, mas info https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS . tal vez te convenga hablar con el dominio al que accedes a ver si hay un API que puedas consultar